# How do you nest navigations inside tabs in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm struggling with a simple concept I think. I want to be able to have 4 tabs at the bottom of my screen but within them `push` or `navigate` to different pages. these pages are "dynamic". I.e. based on the id I supply I get different data back

the example here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/ seems to put the tab inside one of the stacks. but I need the tabs to be rendered on every page

how can I achieve that?

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Sign Up" component={AuthenticateUserScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Create League" component={CreateLeague} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Join League" component={JoinLeague} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Leagues" component={Leagues} />
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)
```

there the tabs I want but say someone clicks on the league with `id 1`, it shows the Leagues component but with different data to say league `id 5` but I don't want league `id` to be show in the tabs menu (for obvious reasons). how do I do this?

Comment: Need some more info. Which screen takes user click and navigate to which screen. If you can elaborate more about your use case would be great.

Comment: so inside Leagues you should be able to click on a list of ids which would then render the same page with different data. but I don't want to be able to go straight to that page from the tab menu. so leagues is a list of leagues and then league-id shows the league with the relevant data corresponding to the id. make sense?

Comment: So Leagues could be a Stack which have 2 screens, list and details. List will navigate to detail with param id. Is this the expected result?

Comment: yeh that kinda makes sense. are you able to quickly pseduo code it out?

Comment: figured it out, thanks for your suggestion it abled me to get there!